# how to create a dynamic drop down list in C# with window forms

Tags: c#, winforms, list, ms-access

I'm trying to build a simple inventory program for a friends cellphone store
I want to use C# and access database to store the data

the DB will have 2 main lists:

1. **devices** - brand, model, color, price, stock,min_stock
2. **parts** - brand, model, description,stock,min_stock

the GUI will use several drop lists
brand will give me : samsung, htc, ect'....
model will give me : I9000,i9100,ect...

the two main problems I have when I try to think how to make it are this:

- Each time new brands and models appear
  so i need an option to add a new model/brand to the database and then update the drop down list to have them automatically
- The drop lists needs to be connected
  so if I choose brand A only brands A models will appear in the model drop list

Comment: What is your Question? What Have you tried? Are you looking for pointers in how to code this?

Comment: Have you tried to rebind the datacontext after an update?

Comment: @Derek, yes... i'm looking for pointers because till now i used static drop lists that i have preconfigured. i just don't know how to make it dynamic so it will fit the need i have for it

Comment: can you upload you code, i am also planning for the mobile cell phone store.
if can you please,
i will add new features also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: don't use Access, use SQL Server 2008 Express. But that's only personal taste.

What you need to do to achieve what you want: Create a typed dataset in Visual Studio that contains one table for brands and one for models. Associate the two tables using a relation on the `brand` column.

Read both tables from the database - first the `brands` table, then the `models` table. Otherwise you'll get an error.

Create a master/detail binding for both lists. To do so, drop two `BindingSource` instances to your form. Associate one of them to the "brands"  list and one to the "devices" list. The datasource for the "brands" `BindingSource` must be set to the `brands` table in the dataset, the datasource for the other `BindingSource` must be set to the **relation** between the two tables. All of this can be one in the designer.

If you have problems setting up the bindings, google for "C# master detail binding dataset".

**EDIT**
Another option - if the database connection is fast - would be to fill the list of brands from the database and whenever a brand is selected, clear and re-fill the list of models from the database on the fly using the selected brand name.

Comment: thx, i will try it this weekend when i have free time to code. any chance you could refer me to a code example of something similar to what i try to create (using Google isn't a problem, knowing how to ask it the right question is)

Comment: did some fast reading... can i read the names for the DB, using distinct to get the "brand" names?

Comment: I'd do a `SELECT DISTINCT Brand FROM ...` for the brand names and a `SELECT * FROM ...` for the models (the models table needs to be filled fully.

Comment: the database will be small (small store & inventory) so i think it wont have speed issues. your edit is the 2nd option i need in the program, the MODEL drop list needs to be connected to the BRAND list

Comment: Both options allow for this. The "master/detail" thing I described first, does the same, only that all data is in memory and thus it is very fast. The second option is easier to program, but requires a database request every time a different item is selected. The first option would be my preferred way, as master/detail connections are pretty comfortable.

Comment: OK, will try to do on the weekend

Comment: How many ppl will have access to this system. Will it be ran from only one machine are do you intend to deply it on multiple machines?

Comment: 1 person, 1 machine... a friend just suggested using access for the gui and DB, need to look into that