# How to update the values in a combobox triggered by another combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have 2 comboboxes in a form.

I'd like the selected value in combobox1 to change when the list in combobox2 gets updated.

For Example: ComboBox1 has names of mobile companies and ComboBox2 containing the list of all mobile phones of that company.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680283/how-to-create-a-dynamic-drop-down-list-in-c-sharp-with-window-forms/13680384#13680384

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you have a dictionary that associates phone models to their manufacturers:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> brandsAndModels = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

public void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    brandsAndModels["Samsung"] = new string[] { "Galaxy S", "Galaxy SII", "Galaxy SIII" };
    brandsAndModels["HTC"] = new string[] { "Hero", "Desire HD" };
}
```

You can get the items to be displayed in the left combo box as:

```
foreach (string brand in brandsAndModels.Keys)
    comboBox1.Items.Add(brand);
```

You do this only once, for example in the form's `Load` event. Note: The `brandsAndModels` dictionary must be an instance variable, not a local variable as we need to access it later on.

Then, you'd have to assign an event handler for the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, in which you replace the items in the second combo box with the items in the array for the selected brand:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox2.Items.Clear();

    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        string brand = brandsAndModels.Keys.ElementAt(comboBox1.SelectedIndex);
        comboBox2.Items.AddRange(brandsAndModels[brand]);
    }
}
```

If all of this came from a database, things would be much nicer using data bindings as described in the answers to the question I've linked in my comment to your question.

Comment: yess sir. the comment question was nice, but the answer which is given is not for beginner i dont know the binding concept and table realtion, its complicated, can you simplify for beginners?
please if you can

Comment: I did in this answer - this answer doesn't use bindings.

Comment: yes i know. i was talking about the commented link,can you simplify the answer which was given by that person in the linked question. which you have given, ohh that answer was given by you only. sorry i didint noticed that
Sorry for my bad english sir, i am not familiar with that

Comment: Why don't you try what I said in *this* answer? **This answer does not use data bindings**. Also, there is no simpler way than using `SelectedIndexChanged` as I wrote in *this* answer.

Comment: yess sir
i have pasted this code in the load event
Dictionary<string, string[]> brandsAndModels = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

            brandsAndModels["Samsung"] = new string[] { "Galaxy S", "Galaxy SII", "Galaxy SIII" };
            brandsAndModels["HTC"] = new string[] { "Hero", "Desire HD" };

            foreach (string brand in brandsAndModels.Keys)
                comboBox1.Items.Add(brand);
and that event code in the event
but the two errors are coming
 The name 'brandsAndModels' does not exist in the current context

Comment: ... it gives you a compiler error in `SelectedIndexChanged`. That's why I said that the dictionary must be an instance variable, not a local variable in the `Load` event. I've edited my code to make it clearer.

Comment: what is instance variable and local variable?

Comment: Variables are only valid within the block of code they are declared in or any block that's included by the current block. A local variable is a variable that's declared within a function. It is called local, because it is only valid within this function and can not be used in other functions. An instance variable (also called "member variable") is declared on class level (outside any functions, but inside the code for a class) and is valid in all functions (also called methods) for the class.

Comment: 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string[]>.KeyCollection' does not contain a definition for 'GetAt' and no extension method 'GetAt' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string[]>.KeyCollection' could be found
this error is coming

Comment: Oops, sorry, my mistake. Replace this by `ElementAt`. I'm fixing my sample code.

Comment: its working, does this code can have simplify? if loop and all, it is little bit complicated to understand by me, such newbies

Comment: As far as I see, this can not be simplified using stuff that's easier to understand than a loop ;-) If you want to get deeper into programming, conditional statements (`if`) and loops (`for`, `foreach`, `while`, etc.) are the fundamentals, which are *absolutely necessary* to understand - so you might as well get familiar with them now than later :-D

Comment: string[] st2 = new string[] { "Galaxy S", "Galaxy SII", "Galaxy SIII" };
 
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Clear();
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1 )
            {
                comboBox2.Items = st2; // it is not happing??
            }
        }
can you tell me

Comment: You can not *assign* an array (`st2`) to the combo box `Items` collection. You can, however, use the `AddRange` method. I'm going to update my code, as this is actually a simplification.

Comment: Also: Please don't start hardcoding things the way you do now - this is *not* good practice for what you are trying to achieve! The approach from my answer is the shortest and easiest while still being most flexible. For example: What if another requirement is that the items in `comboBox1` are sorted? And then you need to insert another brand in the middle? Would you like to update the `if` statements every time? For example: Let's say you have *HTC* and *Samsung* now. Tomorrow you need to insert *LG*. No problem using my approach - lots of work using yours, as you need to update all `if`s.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162839/how-to-transfer-the-text-from-dynamically-generated-user-control-to-a-textbox
CAN YOU HELP ME PLEASE

Answer (score 2):

You must handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of combobox to achieve that

Comment: can you throw some more light how can i achieve this?
i am a beginner and sorry for the bad english

Comment: @shariq_khan select needed combobox and in the Properties windows switch to events and double click SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: i know that but what to write? i dont know the logic part how to do that

Answer (score 2):

As you look new I will explain you step-by-step.

1. Right-Click on ComboBox1 and select properties.
2. This will open the properties panel.
3. From the top of properties panel select event button.
4. List of all events related to combobox will be displayed.
5. From this list double-click on SelectedIndexChanged.
6. private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {} will be created

You can use the following code after this.

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> models = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //initializing combobox1
    comboBox1.Items.Add("Select Company");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("HTC");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("Nokia");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("Sony");

    //select the selected index of combobox1
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

    //initializing model list for each brand
    models["Sony"] = new string[] { "Xperia S", "Xperia U", "Xperia P" };
    models["HTC"] = new string[] { "WildFire", "Desire HD" };
    models["Nokia"] = new string[] { "N97", "N97 Mini" };
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox2.Items.Clear();

    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        string brand = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        if(brand != "" && comboBox1.SelectedIndex > 0)
            foreach (string model in models[brand])
                comboBox2.Items.Add(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: sir, what > -1  in the step?
comboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1

Comment: sir this error is coming in line
The name 'models' does not exist in the current context
 foreach (string model in models[brand])

Comment: have you declared this `Dictionary<string, string[]> models = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();`?

Comment: > -1 means that if the SelectedIndex of comboxBox is greater than -1 means it's `0 = Select Company` or `1 = HTC` or `2 = Nokia` or `3 = Sony`

Comment: You can also use `Breakpoint` with `Visual Studios` and see how the code is working and what values are coming.

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar: Yes i used your approach, because it was easy to understand, but i explained it step-bby-step as the person is new to c#.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162839/how-to-transfer-the-text-from-dynamically-generated-user-control-to-a-textbox
CAN YOU HELP ME PLEASE