# How to refresh combobox winform c#

Tags: c#, oracle, winforms, visual-studio, combobox

i create winform with c# that had two combobox

[The form look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Fahi.png)

combobox1 select company from database

combobox2 select project from database depend on company from combobox1

everything ok when the form loaded but i want to refresh combobox2 when i change company in combobox1

this is my code

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form_AC071503 : Form
    {
        public Form_AC071503()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        OracleCommand cmd1;
        OracleDataAdapter da1;

        OracleCommand cmd2;
        OracleDataAdapter da2;

        private void Form_AC071503_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cmd1 = new OracleCommand("SELECT company,company_name from COMPANIES", Class_All.Connection);
            da1 = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd1);
            da1.Fill(ds, "COMPANIES");
            input_company.DataSource = ds.Tables["COMPANIES"];
            input_company.DisplayMember = "company_name";
            input_company.ValueMember = "company";

            cmd2 = new OracleCommand("SELECT project,project_name from PROJECTS where COMPANY = '" + input_company.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'", Class_All.Connection);
            da2 = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd2);
            da2.Fill(ds, "PROJECTS");
            input_project.DataSource = ds.Tables["PROJECTS"];
            input_project.DisplayMember = "project_name";
            input_project.ValueMember = "project";
        }

        private void Input_company_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /*i try to use the same code in Form_AC071503_Load like this

              cmd2 = new OracleCommand("SELECT project,project_name from PROJECTS where COMPANY = '" + input_company.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'", Class_All.Connection);
              da2 = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd2);
              da2.Fill(ds, "PROJECTS");
              input_project.DataSource = ds.Tables["PROJECTS"];
              input_project.DisplayMember = "project_name";
              input_project.ValueMember = "project";

              but not work because the list project not refresh but increased with new value*/ 
        }
    }
}
```

thank you in advice.

Comment: It looks like you haven't actually implemented any logic in the `Input_company_SelectedIndexChanged` handler.  That's where you'd put the code for refreshing the second combo box.  Use the code you have in `Form_AC071503_Load` as a guide to get started.

Comment: input_project.DataBind()

Comment: is This What U want? [update combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954023/how-to-update-the-values-in-a-combobox-triggered-by-another-combobox)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the ValueChanged event in combobox1.